# flexbox grid under centered flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like an intro section on the left side of a `.container` and a side bar on the right.

On the left side underneath the `.intro` section I want there to be four divs equally spaced like a grid.

I'm having problems with getting the "grid set up". I think part of the problem is that the parent has some flexbox attribute effecting the children.

Requirement : The intro section should be centered in the `.left-side` and the "grid" should not be centered the boxes should take up as much space as necessary to fit **2** on a row with margins in between. The `.intro` should be 80 percent of the width of the leftside.

I don't want to do any major changes to the structure this is just a small sample of how my project is set up.

```css
.container{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto; 
  display: flex;
}
.left-side{
  flex:8;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.side-bar{
  flex: 2;
  height: 100vh;
  background: powderblue;


}
.intro{
  flex:3;
  width:80%;
  height: 300px;
  background: skyblue;
}

.box{
  background: red;
  width: 45%;
  height: 100px;
  flex:4;
  border:1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-side">
    <div class="intro">
      intro
    </div>
    <div class="recent">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="side-bar">
    sidebar
  </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex items can also be flex containers. This enables you to nest multiple containers, with `flex-direction: row` or `column`, in a larger container.

For your layout, you can build a column consisting of two flex items. The first item (`.intro`) has 80% width and can be centered horizontally. The second item (`.recent`) can be a flex container with four items arranged in a 2x2 grid.

```css
.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
.left-side {
    flex: 4;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.side-bar {
    flex: 1;
    background: powderblue;
}
.intro {
    flex: 3;
    height: 300px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: skyblue;
}
.recent {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png");
    background-size: contain;
}
.box {
    margin: 5px;
    flex-basis: calc(50% - 10px);
    height: 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: red;
}

body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-side">
        <div class="intro">intro</div>
        <div class="recent">
            <div class="box">1</div>
            <div class="box">2</div>
            <div class="box">3</div>
            <div class="box">4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="side-bar">
        sidebar
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The thing I didn't like was the border trick . `border: 5px solid transparent;`  didn't work. If I want the user to see art work behind the boxes in the grid how can I do that?

Comment: Just remove the border and use margins instead. Subtract whatever left/right margin you use from the width/flex-basis. Answer revised (with an added background image).